# Running docker from python's venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, python-venv

I have created a python module. Works on ubuntu/xenial with python3.5. I built it and uploaded to python repository. Then I created virtual environment, installed this module and tried to run. As a result I got:

```
(hdfnc_venv) svc@PL1LXD-529389:~/$ python3 -m my_package.my_module -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/svc/hdfnc_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/my_package/my_module.py", line 4, in <module>
    import docker
  File "/home/svc/hdfnc_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/docker/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .api import APIClient
  File "/home/svc/hdfnc_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/docker/api/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .client import APIClient
  File "/home/svc/hdfnc_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 222
    f'Error while fetching server API version: {e}'
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So apparently there are multiple issues here. One is this `invalid syntax` which I suppose is because python3.5 does not recognize f-string syntax introduced in python3.6. Wasn't there an f-string, an exception would be raised anyway.

The bigger problem is why it there is error with just importing docker. Docker is properly installed on this machine, so is the module `docker (5.0.3)` in my venv. The module works when I run it directly in the system from the source code, not from my venv installation. Also when I run it this way, python3.5 works just fine, so `invalid_syntax` is not a problem anymore - most likely python didn't reach this part of the code, which means it managed to import docker module (also 5.0.3) without any problem.

Comment: Can you do `import sys; print(sys.version)` and also `import docker; print(docker.__version__)` in the environment where it runs fine?

Comment: well, what does it help you if docker is installed, but the docker lib you're trying to use is not there in a version compatible with your venv? So, change your venv to not include system-wide packages, and install the docker client library inside your venv in a version that works for the python there.

Comment: @decorator-factory: `3.5.2 (default, Jan 26 2021, 13:30:48)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]`, printed docker version is 4.1.0. So it is not 5.0.3 as I assumed. I have both python3.5 and python3.7 installed, version 5.0.3 is for python3.7.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - I installed docker client inside my venv. As my previous comment states, after all it is in a different version than my system version, so it should work with python3.5

Comment: I don't know how you've installed it into your venv, but usually, when you install a python package, it won't let you install under an incompatible Python version, so, hm, something's wrong here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - Inside venv I installed it with just `pip install docker`. It installed version 5.0.3. I also tried to run `python3 -m pip install docker` with the same version installed. I also have python3.7 installed in the system and docker 5.0.3 works with it, but not with python3.5. In the system each python has a proper version of docker package installed, but in venv the wrong one is installed.